# Boost async_read doesn't give me an "end of frame" flag

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm still working on some kind of client for communication with an IP Camera. Now I have the following issue:

I send a request to the camera ( a `RTSP DESCRIBE`in particular ). Now I get it's answer which looks like this:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Thu, Jan 01 1970 00:31:41 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.0.42/mpeg4?mode=Live&stream=-1&buffer=0&seek=0&fps=100&    metainfo=/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 517
```

This is the header of the answer, followed by a so called `Session Description` which has the size shown in the field `Content-Length`. Actually I don't care much for the `Session Description` , I'm just interested in the `Content-Base` field. But still, since there is some communication following on the same socket, I need to get rid of all the data.

For receiving'm using the `async_read` calls from `boost::asio`. 
My code looks ( simplified ) like this:

```
CommandReadBuffer::CallbackFromAsyncWrite()
{
boost::asio::async_read_until(*m_Socket, m_ReceiveBuffer,"\r\n\r\n",
            boost::bind(&CommandReadBuffer::handle_rtsp_describe, this->shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

This one reads at least the header ( shown above ) since its terminated by a blank line. As usual for `async_write` it just reads some more of the data, but nevermind. Now to the next callback function:

```
void CommandReadBuffer::handle_rtsp_describe(const boost::system::error_code& err,size_t bytesTransferred)
{
std::istream response_stream(&m_ReceiveBuffer);
std::string header;
// Just dump the data on the console 
while (std::getline(response_stream, header))
{
   // Normally I would search here for the desired content-base field
   std::cout << header << "\n";
}
 boost::asio::async_read(*m_Socket, m_ReceiveBuffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
         boost::bind(&CommandReadBuffer::handle_rtsp_setup, this->shared_from_this(),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Now this works fine as well, if I print out the number of received bytes it's always 215.

Now we go on to the critical callback:

```
void CommandReadBuffer::handle_rtsp_setup(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytesTransferred)
{
std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
    if (!err)
    {
      // Write all of the data that has been read so far.
      std::cout << &m_ReceiveBuffer;

    // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
    m_DeadlineTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(&CommandReadBuffer::handleTimeout, this->shared_from_this(),boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      boost::asio::async_read(*m_Socket, m_ReceiveBuffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
             boost::bind(&CommandReadBuffer::handle_rtsp_setup, this->shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
{
  std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "End of Frame " << err.message() << "\n";
}
}
```

This part reads 220 Bytes. If I look at console Output from this call and compare it with the actualy payload of the frame ( as seen in Wireshark ) I can see that all data has been received. Now I would actually assume that `async_read` would set me the `eof` error. But instead the return code of `error` is `success` and so it calls `async_read` again. This time there is no data to be received and it never calls the callback function ( since there will be no more incoming data ).

Now I actually don't know how I could determine that all data has been sent. Actually I would expect the error flag to be set.

Now this is very similar to the implementation of the Boost Example for an Async HTTP client. Also it is done the same way in the [Example Boost Async HTTP Client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp). I implemented this in another call and there it actually works.

Now in my opinion it should make no difference for the `async_read` call wether it is HTTP or RTSP - end of frame is end of frame, if there is no more data to read.

I'm also aware that according to the boost documentation I am using

```
void async_read(
    AsyncReadStream & s,
    basic_streambuf< Allocator > & b,
    CompletionCondition completion_condition,
    ReadHandler handler);
```

which means the function will continue until

> ```
> The supplied buffer is full (that is, it has reached maximum size).
> The completion_condition function object returns 0.
> ```

So if there is no more data to read, it just continues.
But I also tried the overloaded function without the `CompletionCondition` parameter, which should return when an error occurs ( `EOF` !!! ) - But this just won't callback either...

Any suggestions? I just don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written an RTSP client and server library using boost asio and can offer the following advice:
The RTSP message syntax is generic: there is no need for different DESCRIBE and SETUP handlers. In general

- write an RTSP request
- to read the response do a `boost::asio::async_read_until("\r\n\r\n")`
- then check for the `Content-Length` header
- if content_length > 0 do a `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(content_length)`

Further, why are you expecting an EOF? The connection is still open: the server is waiting for either another SETUP or a PLAY request and typically won't close the connection until the RTSP TCP connection has been timed out, which has a default value of 60 seconds according to [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326).

If in your application, you have completed interaction with the RTSP server, close the connection after you have read the response.

Comment: Good point with the EOF ... I maybe got something wrong in my mind! Well I actually went kinda in the direction you are telling me. But one question at this point: When I receive the reply to a SETUP or a PLAY request I never get the field "content-length" in the header...is it never there or just in  this particular case?

Comment: The SETUP and PLAY requests do not have a message body. According to RFC2326 it is just the DESCRIBE and GET_PARAMETER requests that return a message body in the response: "...all methods that return a message body. Within this specification, DESCRIBE and GET_PARAMETER fall into this class."

Comment: Allright okay, I think I get it all now! Thank you for your help!!